# Image to Byte[] harder than thought 2 challenges

Tags: arrays, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, bitmap

This is my 5th post over a month trying to solve what I thought was a simple problem: Write and read a small bitmap to a class.
My class:

```
public class Task
public byte? TaskImage { get; set; }
```

I recreate the bitmap in the controller after an edit, the bitmap is contained in System.Drawing. This line writes to a folder as a test. It works.

```
mybmp.Save("C:\\temp\\lot1.bmp",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

I think this puts it in a memory stream as a .bmp:  Should this be .gif??

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
mybmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.bmp);
```

CHALLENGE 1 provide inline code to convert to byte[] and write to class.

```
Task.TaskImage = 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Later I pass the data via a viewmodel to my view and use the ForEach item concept to display the image.

CHALLENGE 2 code to display in view table:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.TaskImage.Value)" />
```

This code has been provided by a contributor but causes this error.

```
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'byte[]'
```

It was suggested I ask a new question. 
I'm a beginner so please be explicit. When I have a working answer I'll go back and post answers to my earlier posts to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Challenge 1 the write bitmap into a byte[] field:

```
mybmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
            ms.Close();
            var lottoupdate = db.Lots             //each task row contains the lotid to which
                   .Where(i => i.LotID == lotID)  //it is associated. Find the LotID then
                   .Single();                    // update the taskimage field in the lot class
             byteArray = ms.ToArray();
            lottoupdate.TaskImage = byteArray;
            db.Entry(lottoupdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

There was a error in the lottoupdate.TaskImage=byteArray; line  because TaskImage was nullable.

```
public class Task
public byte? TaskImage { get; set; }
```

So I removed the? therefore requiring data.  I now seed the field.

Challenge 2 With the TaskImage byte[] passed in the viewmodel, display the image in the view table:

```
    <text>       @{ 

                 string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(@item.TaskImage);
                 String imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);

                    }


     </text> 
    <td><img src="@imageSrc" alt="Lot chart" border="0" /></td>
```

This displays the image in a table row. I needed the 'text' tags because html5 did not like the razor code without it. Note that I am not testing for null data, probably should. My program seeds an "base" image into the db.

I hope this helps someone else, it took about 30 hours of looking for this beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are properly saving the byte array and you already have contents of your image as a `byte[]`

why don't you try this, if you are using MVC4

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Controller", new{id=@Model.Id})"  
        alt = "img" />
```

where `GetImage` is :

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
    var imageByteArray= GetImageByte(id)
    return File(imageByteArray, "Image/jpg");
}
```

Comment: No I'm asking for the MVC4 inline code to convert the bitmap to the byte[] and then save it. "CHALLANGE 1 provide inline code to convert to byte[] and write to class"@Manish

Comment: I'm a beginner. Where would the ActionResult code go? In the controller? Wouldn't that mean a 2nd round trip for each image? The ViewModel already has the image, can't I convert it in the view?@Manish

Comment: Is that part of my problem? Should I, [must I], convert it before the viewmodel is passed? What would that inline code look like? Beginner looking for solutions.@Manish

Comment: yes, that would mean second roundtrip to server, but since your ViewModel already has the image, why don't you convert the byte into string and have it in viewmodel itself, so that all you have to do on the view is to assign it like `@Model.ImageData`

Comment: The viewmodel has a collection of TaskImages, therefor I would need to create an array of converted images and then pass that array. Instead could I add a null field to my model that could hold the converted image prior to passing? What would the type be? @Manish